AuthenticationService causes automatic navigation
I have a login screen in angular. But every time I try to open it (localhost:4200/login) it opens this but than jumps to localhost:4200.
import { Component, signal } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GenericPanelComponent } from '../../common/generic-panel/generic-panel.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { TokenService } from '../../token/token.service';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { AuthenticationRequest, AuthenticationService } from '../../../services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [GenericPanelComponent, MatCardModule, MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatButtonModule],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrl: './login.component.scss'
})
export class LoginComponent {
  authRequest: AuthenticationRequest = { email: '', password: ''};
  errorMsg: Array<string> = [];

  primary: string = 'purple';
  accent: string = 'green';

  email = signal('');
  password = signal('');
  
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthenticationService,
    private tokenService: TokenService
  ) { };

  login(): void {
     this.errorMsg = [];
  }

  registerConsumer(): void {
    this.router.navigate( ['register-consumer']);
  }

  registerVendor(): void {
    this.router.navigate( ['register-vendor']);
  }
}

The funny thing is, that if I comment out the line "private authService: AuthenticationService," the login page stays in the browser. The AuthenticationService has been generated via open api. I'd like to share my authentication.service.ts but need a hint, how I can provide this to you.
According to Naren Murali (thanks for your comment), here are the constructor and the variables:
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

    protected basePath = 'http://localhost:8088/api/v1';
    public defaultHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    public configuration = new Configuration();
    public encoder: HttpParameterCodec;

    constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient, @Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string|string[], @Optional() configuration: Configuration) {
        if (configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
        if (typeof this.configuration.basePath !== 'string') {
            const firstBasePath = Array.isArray(basePath) ? basePath[0] : undefined;
            if (firstBasePath != undefined) {
                basePath = firstBasePath;
            }

            if (typeof basePath !== 'string') {
                basePath = this.basePath;
            }
            this.configuration.basePath = basePath;
        }
        this.encoder = this.configuration.encoder || new CustomHttpParameterCodec();
    }

The defined routes are:
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'register-consumer',
      component: RegisterConsumerComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'register-vendor',
      component: RegisterVendorComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'activate-account',
      component: ActivateAccountComponent
    }
];


update it on the question, "I'd like to share my authentication.service.ts but need a hint, how I can provide this to you.", require the constructor part and the variables defined. also is there any ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit code in the login component?

Hi Naren Murali, thank you for your comment. I added the variables and constructor to my case above. The login.component.ts is complete, there is no ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit.

@Naren Murali: Hi I found out that it stays on localhost:4200/login as long as I do not have the httpClient in the contructor:
constructor(@Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string|string[], @Optional() configuration: Configuration) ... works.
But I need the HttpClient to get in contact with the server. Is it a version problem?

@Naren Murali: Thank you for your help. I got it working now. Have a nice day.

Ok, forget it, FORGET IT!!!!
I just found an error message on the console that didn't caught my eyes until now: No provider for HttpClient.
With that it was easy to find the solution under No provider for HttpClient.
Now it is not redirected anymore. My bad, sorry.
